# insert checkboxlist values to db

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, checkboxlist

I have check List like this

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CA" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        DataTextField="MNU_NAME" DataValueField="MNU_ID">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DataConnectionString2 %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DataConnectionString2.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT ID, MNU_ID, MNU_NAME, MNU_TAB FROM MENU_LIST WHERE (MNU_TAB = 'CA')" 
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And I Am Trying To insert the Selected Values of CheckBoxlist into DB like this

```
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
if (TextBox1.Text == null || TextBox1.Text == "")
{
    Response.Write("Enter Email");
}
foreach (ListItem li in CA.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected == true)
    {
        oda.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USR_MNU(LNK_NAME,USR_EMAIL,ACTIVE) values('" + li.Value + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "',1)";
        oda.InsertCommand.Connection = con;
        oda.InsertCommand.Connection.Open();
        oda.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        oda.InsertCommand.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

When I Press the Button to Insert the the Values i got this error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Please any One Guide me How To Insert the only selected Values of Check boxlist to DB.

Comment: where you are getting this error?

Comment: on this line `oda.InsertCommand.CommandText.....`

Comment: debug your code and let me know that you are getting right value in li.value....

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a new command, but not associated it with the adapter.

So, you need to add this to create the command within the adapter:

```
oda.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand();
```

This will mean you can get rid of the line:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Justin-Harvey right,
But You not need DataAdapter (It is designed to mediate Database-DataSet).
Here is your code without DataAdapter:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
if (TextBox1.Text == null || TextBox1.Text == "")
{
    Response.Write("Enter Email");
}
foreach (ListItem li in CA.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected == true)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USR_MNU(LNK_NAME,USR_EMAIL,ACTIVE) values('" + li.Value + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "',1)";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```